# Is it possible for the "log a call" task to automatically open up when agents receive or make AWS call?

Tags: tasks, servicecloud, log-a-call, amazon-connect-salesforce-cti

My instance is currently using Amazon Connect as our phone system. I am trying to have the "log a call" task automatically open up when an agent is either making or receiving a call like in the screenshot below. I would then like to populate some custom fields under this activity with call information (like call recording) with information from the call itself. I initially tried to execute this with flows, but that would just complete the task and not leave it open for the agent to take notes. The idea here is that the moment the agent is on a call, they have a place to start taking notes already open on their screen. [image]

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a setting under configuration which you need to enable. It is called "Always Show Salesforce Log a Call Window"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).